# How do I pass an object to a button click event handler in WPF? C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building out a simple ToDoList app using C# and WPF.
The goal is that when the button is clicked. The text in a TextBox will be added as a new element in a List which is an existing object instance.

To do this I've updated the Button click event handler's signature to include a parameter to pass the List object.
When I compile this code I get an error thrown from my XAML file at the line which contains the Click="AddTaskButton_Click"

Error: **No overload for 'AddTaskButton_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'**

What could be throwing this error? I've seen other code samples where this compiles fine.
Is there another way to accomplish passing "data" or an object to an event handler in WPF? I'm new to WPF.

**XAML**

```
<Button
x:Name="AddTaskButton"  Content="+ Add"  
Click="AddTaskButton_Click">
</Button>
```

**Backend C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> taskList = new Tasklist {"Task A", "Task B", "Task C"}

        AddTaskButton.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => { AddTaskButton_Click(sender, e, taskList); };
    }

    private void AddTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, List<string> taskList)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the Click="AddTaskButton_Click" in Xaml.  You are setting the handler in the code behind.

Comment: What's `Tasklist` with a capital `T` and a little `l`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a Parameter to a Button\_Click event in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680854/adding-a-parameter-to-a-button-click-event-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XAML code

```xml
<Button
x:Name="AddTaskButton"  Content="+ Add" >
</Button>
```

You've added an eventhander on the XAML code too. You can only add event handlers with 2 parameters: an `object` and a `RoutedEventArgs`. Your XAML code adds an other event handler to `AddTaskButton_Click` witch has a 3<sup>th</sup> parameter type of `List<string>`.

Keep the C# code as is. It adds also an event handler on the correct way using the lambda expression at the constructor. But add a semicolon where you declare `taskList` and change `Tasklist` *(with a capital `T` and a little `l`)* to `List<string>`.

Comment: Appreciate this. I didn't realize you could specify the whole event handler in the c# file without having to do another link in the XAML file.